Movie about a man reborn after dying on subway tracks
Help me find this movie:
A guy at the beginning of the movie dies on the tracks of a subway.
Then he gets to another life where he is waiting for a car or bus in a dessert station. I think he and everyone else knows that he died and this place where he came to is where we all have to go after death.
In this new life he receives a job as an executive in a corporation located in a large and luxurious building. He works with a computer in a luxurious office. He seems to fall in love with whom he wants, he takes several women to bed and he seems to fall in love for a very young one, but he is not satisfied with this life where there's no flavor at all. He tries to leave the place by committing suicide, but he always comes back to the same place, sometimes with his body shattered but he always heals.
He almost accidentally discovers someone who is in the same search, but this someone has found a fissure to the "real" world ... 
He uses a jackhammer to widen the fissure and then he is caught, put in an airplane and sent to "another world" which looks very wild (rocks and dust).
I think it is spoken in German (almost sure it is not dubbed)

This is the plot of the Norwegian fantasy drama The Bothersome Man from 2006.

Forty-year-old Andreas arrives in a strange city with no memory of how he got there. He is presented with a job, an apartment - even a wife. But before long, Andreas notices that something is wrong. Andreas makes an attempt to escape the city, but he discovers there's no way out. Andreas meets Hugo, who has found a crack in a wall in his cellar. Beautiful music streams out from the crack. Maybe it leads to "the other side"? A new plan for escape is hatched.

It starts when he jumps in front of a subway train. Here's the trailer:



